# Why do all javascript functions execute when I click on only one?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I am trying to create a dynamic menu bar whose selections change as I click on different items.

Here is the simple HTML

```
<div class="global">

   <nav class='menubar'>
      <button class='btn websites'>Websites</button>
      <button class='btn contacts'>Contacts</button>
      <button class='btn finance'>Finance</button>
   </nav>

   <div class="workspace">

   </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript

```
// click on navbar only
$($nav_menu).on('click',  (e)=> {
    console.log("Menu Bar")
    $nav_menu.load('/main_menu.html');
})

// click on any button
$($nav_menu).on('click', $btn_websites, ()=> {
    //$nav_menu.html("");
    console.log("Websites")
    //$nav_menu.load('/website_menu.html');
})

// click on any button
$($nav_menu).on('click', $btn_contacts, ()=> {
    //$nav_menu.html("");
    console.log("Contacts")
    //$nav_menu.load('/contact_menu.html');
})

// click on any button
$($nav_menu).on('click', $btn_finance, ()=>{
    //$nav_menu.html("");
    console.log("Finance")
   // $nav_menu.load('/finance_menu.html');
})
```

The problem is that regardless of which item I click on, or if I click only on the menu bar itself, all of the functions are executed. Console log shows that each function has fired.

Thank you

Comment: Is `$btn_websites` a jquery object or string selector?

Comment: Without knowing what `$btn_websites` / `$btn_contacts` / `$btn_finance` is, any solution would be just a guess.  These *must* be strings and the outdated  `$`  implies these are jquery collections, which don't work for filters on event delegation, so are probably getting ignored, thus your problem.   Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do apart from what you are going is as below

```
$(".menubar .websites").on('click',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    load('/website_menu.html');
});

$(".menubar .finance").on('click',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    load('/finance_menu.html');
});

$(".menubar .contacts").on('click',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    load('/contacts_menu.html');
});
```

You will have to add another link to open the main menu.
Make sure you have the load function to open the requested page ie

```
function load(page_path){
$.get(page_path, function(data) {
    $(".workspace").html(data);
      alert("Page hasloaded.");
    });
}
```

Comment: From the description, OP is recreating the menu without loading the page, hence the use of / attempted use of event delegation.  Changing to non-event delegation will be unlikely to work unless OP also changes how/when the events are assigned, which your answer don't mention.

Comment: Have you defined "$nav_menu"? It is not appearing anywhere.

Comment: You have not also defined $btn_websites, $btn_contacts, and $btn_finance in your code. Please edit and include all your code.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// assuming the following...

const $nav_menu = $("nav.menubar");
const $btn_websites = ".btn.websites";
const $btn_contacts = ".btn.contacts";
const $btn_finance = ".btn.finance";

const $workspace = $("div.workspace");

$($nav_menu).on('click', $btn_websites, (event) => {
  console.log("Load Websites");
  $workspace.html(event.target.textContent);
})

$($nav_menu).on('click', $btn_contacts, (event) => {
  console.log("Load Contacts");
  $workspace.html(event.target.textContent);
})

$($nav_menu).on('click', $btn_finance, (event) => {
  console.log("Load Finance");
  $workspace.html(event.target.textContent);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="global">

  <nav class='menubar'>
    <button class='btn websites'>Websites</button>
    <button class='btn contacts'>Contacts</button>
    <button class='btn finance'>Finance</button>
  </nav>

  <div class="workspace">
  </div>
</div>
```